# How are ulimits determined for processes running in unpriviledged containers?

Tags: ulimit, systemd-nspawn

Recently, while I was building something in an unprivileged nspawn container (for CI), with the host system running arch linux, I repeatedly ran into an EMFILE error, from yarn, indicating that I'm trying to open too many files.

I tried:

1. increasing `ulimit -n` in the container and host, and tweaking `/etc/limits.conf`. But, no dice - higher limits were reported, but the errors still occurred.
2. Setting `LimitNOFILE` in the `.nspawn` file for the container to a very high value. Still nothing (with the nspawn invocation including `--settings=override`).
3. setting `LimitNOFILE=infinity` in `ulimit.conf`, following this advice: https://serverfault.com/questions/848088/how-to-set-max-file-descriptors-for-a-container
4. increasing `fs.inotify.max_user_instances`, and `fs.inotify.max_user_watches` via `sysctl`, since these can [apparently](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/64919108/error-emfile-too-many-open-files-watch-unless-i-use-sudo) cause an EMFILE error.

What worked in the end was switching to a privileged container by setting `PrivateUsers=off`, following the conversation here: https://bbs.archlinux.org/viewtopic.php?id=232804. This also required running the command that was failing as root (within the container).

So, my question is: *HOW does usernamespacing interact with ulimits*, and *WHY did this fix my problem* when the previous steps didn't?

Bonus points for a good mental model that will help the next person who has to debug this kind of thing.